# How to access each element with a certain key in a dictionary

Tags: python, api, dictionary

I'm pulling data from an API and the result looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "year": "2020",
    "quarter": "1",
    "input": "31080",
    "crosswalk_type": "cbsa-zip",
    "results": [
      {
        "geoid": "90250",
        "res_ratio": 0.006727469865159593,
        "bus_ratio": 0.003776624306425631,
        "oth_ratio": 0.013730729472865928,
        "tot_ratio": 0.006843653586843295
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90046",
        "res_ratio": 0.00655721932565345,
        "bus_ratio": 0.0033795987438371543,
        "oth_ratio": 0.008322582982031358,
        "tot_ratio": 0.006338246981004679
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90025",
        "res_ratio": 0.005284695525716839,
        "bus_ratio": 0.006336137461965276,
        "oth_ratio": 0.0112871723000365,
        "tot_ratio": 0.005749518826354573
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90509",
        "res_ratio": 0,
        "bus_ratio": 0,
        "oth_ratio": 0.000002786268156019872,
        "tot_ratio": 1.6597918089938143e-7
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to extract a list just of the elements with the key "geoid" (these are zip codes). How do I iterate over the list to pull out these elements?

Comment: If your dictionary is called `d` then try `[res["geoid"] for res in d["data"]["results"]]`

Comment: @khawes as my answer was before the other one and the 1:1 code worked for you, can you mark my answer as a correct one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "year": "2020",
        "quarter": "1", 
        ...

geoids = [code['geoid'] for code in data['data']['results']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by naming your `dictionary` into the variable `a` and then calling between the `[]` brackets the name of a key. For your `dictionary` and desired output it will look like this:

```
a = {
  "data": {
    "year": "2020",
    "quarter": "1",
    "input": "31080",
    "crosswalk_type": "cbsa-zip",
    "results": [
      {
        "geoid": "90250",
        "res_ratio": 0.006727469865159593,
        "bus_ratio": 0.003776624306425631,
        "oth_ratio": 0.013730729472865928,
        "tot_ratio": 0.006843653586843295
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90046",
        "res_ratio": 0.00655721932565345,
        "bus_ratio": 0.0033795987438371543,
        "oth_ratio": 0.008322582982031358,
        "tot_ratio": 0.006338246981004679
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90025",
        "res_ratio": 0.005284695525716839,
        "bus_ratio": 0.006336137461965276,
        "oth_ratio": 0.0112871723000365,
        "tot_ratio": 0.005749518826354573
      },
      {
        "geoid": "90509",
        "res_ratio": 0,
        "bus_ratio": 0,
        "oth_ratio": 0.000002786268156019872,
        "tot_ratio": 1.6597918089938143e-7
      }
    ]
  }
}

geoids = [x['geoid'] for x in a['data']['results']]
```

Comment: The last line of this answer will not work. I think you meant `a['data']['results'][0]['geoid']`. Also, this does not address the original question of iterating over the ilst of items in the `results` key.

Comment: @gallen thank you for that - I have made a typo and a logical error by copying the wrong line from an IDE. I have fixed it by now, thank you for pointing it :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Pesky copy-paste errors get the best of us at times.